emulator I/MESA logg
iam using MacBook  for flutter App Development and using vs code , when i try to debug the App in android emulator from vscode
in debugg console
got these type of logs
I/MESA    ( 4858): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 161
I/MESA    ( 4858): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007c514f2ed0 hos timage handle 0x7000400000721
I/MESA    ( 4858): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 169
I/MESA    ( 4858): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007c515172d0 hos timage handle 0x7000400000722
how to avoid these any permanant solution
Emulator Settings
Explore the emulator's advanced settings to see if there are options to adjust log verbosity or filter specific log categories.
